# Why does a do-nothing program, written in C, take up 14KB even when compiled with -nostdlib option in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, executable

I was reading an article on static and dynamic linking of libraries in C which suggested that I should compile a program which simply returns 0 through the main function and compare its size with and without the `-nostdlib` option in GCC. The author's executable showed a drastic reduction (from 10KiB to 3KiB) whereas mine simply showed a reduction from 16KiB to 14KiB.

What is the reason behind this? Is this because of a change in the GCC versions used? If so, what's a do-nothing program have in it that takes up 14KiB?

**EDIT:** GCC Version 9.2.1, Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: What OS? It matters.  See this. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418354/understanding-what-a-linux-binary-is-doing

Comment: you might like [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

Comment: @pmg Following the instructions there, I am still unable to shave it down below 14KiB. And I am programming in Assembly now.

Comment: it depends on other compile options and the size of the start-up code